# How to fix MYSQL between date not giving accurate results?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
SELECT
IF
    (
        SUM( t.debit )>= SUM( t.credit ),
        SUM( t.debit ) - SUM( t.credit ),
    SUM( t.credit ) - SUM( t.debit )) AS Balance,
    
    IF(SUM( t.debit )>= SUM( t.credit ) ,"Profit", "Loss") AS status 
FROM
    transactions AS t 
WHERE
    t.userId = 1 AND t.dateIssued BETWEEN  '2021-07-09' AND '2021-07-10';
```

I expected to give 6000 as the output because the between should be date inclusive

[image]

Comment: you should provide the create table and with data in it as **text**, and so complete the [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dateIssued` is not a `Date`, it is a `DateTime`/`timestamp`.
So, when you compare its value `2021-07-10 13:11:12` to dates like `'2021-07-09'` and `'2021-07-10'` the comparison is interpreted as:

```
'2021-07-10 13:11:12' BETWEEN '2021-07-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-10 00:00:00'
```

which returns `false`.

Convert `dateIssued` to `Date` with the function `Date()` and then compare:

```
WHERE t.userId = 1 AND DATE(t.dateIssued) BETWEEN  '2021-07-09' AND '2021-07-10';
```

For better performance you should consider writing the conditions without `BETWEEN` and the function `Date()`:

```
WHERE t.userId = 1 
  AND t.dateIssued >=  '2021-07-09' 
  AND t.dateIssued < '2021-07-11';
```

Comment: thank you  it worked, I learned a lot from you.